# How to display a stream of images in Python2

Tags: python, python-2.7, stream

I have an application where I get multiple successive images as OpenCV2 Matrix via a callback and have to display them as they come in. I tried with `cv2.imshow` and matplotlibs API, from the animate module to all variants of `plt.show(block=False)` that are found online but nothing seems to work.

Also I am on Ubuntu 18.04 and Python 2.7.

So given I have a function:

```
def image_callback(cvmat):
    display_image()
```

And assuming this function is called with about 40 Hz and I want to display the cvmat as a video, so open a window and keep updating its content, how could I do that? As I said, both opencv and matplotlib couldn't do it for some reason. Are there any other alternatives around? PIL might be an option but I have 0 experiences with it and also never saw it being used that way.

Attempt#1: cv2 `cv2.imshow("Title", cvmat)`. This doesn't work because it's blocking.

Attempt#2: During init call `plt.ion()`, then display images with `plt.imshow(cvmat)`. This worked on an archlinux host running xfce4, but not on Ubuntu 18.04 with GNOME. I don't know if that makes a difference here but I think that has to be it.

Attempt#3: Matplotlib Animations. This just drew the first image that came in and never updated. Same behaviour when I added proper locking.

```
class Streamer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.curr_img = None
        self._curr_img_is_new = False
        self._fig = plt.figure()
        self._ax = self._fig.add_subplot(111)
        self._animation = animation.FuncAnimation(self._fig,
                                                  self.__show_image,
                                                  interval=30)

    def __show_image(self, _):
        if self._curr_img_is_new and self.curr_img:
            self._ax.clear()
            cvmat = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(
                deepcopy(self.current_img_message),
                desired_encoding='passthrough')
            print("(__show_image)Got an image!")
            self._ax.imshow(cvmat)
            self._curr_img_is_new = False
    def set_new_image(self, cvmat):
       self.curr_img = cvmat
       self._curr_img_is_new = True

s = Streamer()
plt.show()
def image_callback(cvmat):
    s.set_new_image(cvmat)
```

Comment: Could you try again with the imshow approach, adding "cv2.waitKey(1)" right after the imshow call?

Comment: that didn't work during my tests on arch, so I didn't even try it yet on this machine. Gonna take me a while to set that up again as I didn't commit that attempt.

Comment: I cannot get the cv2 one to work right now because of some GTK XORG forwarding error through docker.. Though the fact that it didn't work on archlinux doesn't give me high hopes that it'd work on the much older version as there probably hasn't been any changes besides bugfixes to Python2 packages for a while now